# I can't compile anymore: AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 0","sources":

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

For a few days I have not been able to compile my project with the MacBook anymore while I am able to compile it with a Windows PC, despite not having changed anything.
Until a few days ago I was able to compile without any problem but now I can no longer compile on MacBook even the previous releases this happens only on MacBook instead on Windows PC I can still compile without any problem.

Any ideas on what might have happened?

Compiling on MacBook I get that error, here full stacktrace:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 0","sources":[{"file":"/MyProject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/APMSPlugin/devGms/debug/57.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
org.gradle.workers.WorkerExecutionException: There was a failure while executing work items
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.workerExecutionException(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:270)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.await(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:252)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexArchiveBuilderTaskDelegate.doProcess(DexArchiveBuilderTaskDelegate.kt:274)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexArchiveBuilderTask.doTaskAction(DexArchiveBuilderTask.kt:275)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:66)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask.taskAction(NewIncrementalTask.kt:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:506)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:342)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:142)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process: /MyProject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/APMSPlugin/devGms/debug/57.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction.run(DexWorkAction.kt:59)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process: /MyProject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/APMSPlugin/devGms/debug/57.jar
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:214)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process: /MyProject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/APMSPlugin/devGms/debug/57.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkActionKt.process(DexWorkAction.kt:193)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkActionKt.processNonIncrementally(DexWorkAction.kt:159)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkActionKt.launchProcessing(DexWorkAction.kt:86)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction.run(DexWorkAction.kt:49)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:141)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:118)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkActionKt.process(DexWorkAction.kt:189)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position: Lretrofit/client/ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest;<init>(Lretrofit/client/Request;)V, origin: /MyProject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/APMSPlugin/devGms/debug/57.jar:retrofit/client/ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest.class
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process: /MyProject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/APMSPlugin/devGms/debug/57.jar
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.2.71.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.a0.a(SourceFile:89)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:116)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 0
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.r.b(SourceFile:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.r.c(SourceFile:5)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.u.c(SourceFile:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.r.o.V.a(SourceFile:4164)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.o.a(SourceFile:619)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.S.a(SourceFile:259)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.p.a(SourceFile:130)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.p.b(SourceFile:11)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position: Lretrofit/client/ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest;<init>(Lretrofit/client/Request;)V, origin: /MyProject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/APMSPlugin/devGms/debug/57.jar:retrofit/client/ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest.class
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.p.a(SourceFile:108)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.h1.a(SourceFile:39)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.M1.a(SourceFile:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.T.a(SourceFile:603)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.a0.a(SourceFile:124)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.T.c(SourceFile:12)
Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 0]


> Task :app:dexBuilderDevGmsDebug FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDevGmsDebug'.
> There was a failure while executing work items
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
      > Failed to process: /MyProject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/APMSPlugin/devGms/debug/57.jar
```

This is my build.bradle (Global):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath 'com.dynatrace.tools.android:gradle-plugin:8.+'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10'
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Define versions in a single place
ext {
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    mockitoVersion = '1.10.19'
    powerMockito = '1.6.2'
    hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
}
```

and this is build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    ndkVersion "21.3.6528147"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.vit.ant"
        versionName "9.1.0"
        versionCode 8
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 31
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }

    task ndkClean(type: Delete) {
        delete fileTree('.externalNativeBuild') {
            exclude defaultConfig.ndk.abiFilters.collect { '**/' + it }
        }
    }
    tasks.findByPath(':clean').dependsOn ndkClean

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings false
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                println("Signing Key: " + RELEASE_STORE_FILE + ", alias: " + RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS)
                storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled true
            isDefault true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
            isDefault true
        }
        mock {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".mock"
        }
        coll {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".coll"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        gms {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/gms/java']
            //Google Services plugin - firebase dependency for push notification
            apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
            project.ext.set('usesGms', true)
            project.ext.set('usesHms', false)
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.12.4'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3"
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.4'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit1-okhttp3-client:1.1.0'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.31.2'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.31.2'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.31.2'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.31.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.uuid:java-uuid-generator:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'de.halfbit:pinned-section-listview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.10'
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.9.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.8'
    implementation 'de.adorsys.android:securestoragelibrary:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.dynatrace.agent:agent-android:8.+'
    implementation 'com.whiteelephant:monthandyearpicker:1.3.0'

    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-all:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$rootProject.ext.hamcrestVersion"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
    androidTestImplementation("junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion") {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation 'com.whiteelephant:monthandyearpicker:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0'
    gmsImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    gmsImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.j256.two-factor-auth:two-factor-auth:1.3'
    implementation 'com.cleafy.mobile.detection.android:agent:3.5.0:release@aar'
    implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.19.4"
    implementation 'com.kofax.mobile:sdk:3.6.0.0.0.685@aar'
    implementation 'com.kofax.android.abc:xvrs:3.5.0.1.0.450@jar'
    implementation 'com.kofax.mobile:barcodeparser:3.5.0.0.0.12@jar'
    implementation 'com.manateeworks:manatee:2.5.0.0.0.69@jar'
    implementation 'com.kofax.android:isg:3.5.0.1.0.868@jar'
    implementation 'com.kofax.mobile:commonextractionengine:3.5.0.1.0.389@jar'
    implementation 'com.onespan:RootDetectionSDK:4.31.3@jar'
    implementation 'com.onespan:UtilitiesSDK:4.31.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.esotericsoftware:kryo:5.1.1'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.70'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the solution and I am reporting it here for the benefit of anyone who might encounter the same problem.
The error was due to a library with a bug.
In the global build.gradle I have addressed the Dynatrace classpath like this:

```
classpath 'com.dynatrace.tools.android:gradle-plugin:8.+'
```

and in the build.gradle: app the Dynatrace library like so:

```
implementation 'com.dynatrace.agent: agent-android: 8. +'
```

The latest version of the Dynatrace lib at the moment is [8.249.1.1004](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.dynatrace.tools.android/gradle-plugin) and it has the bug mentioned above.
It was enough for me to change the addressing of the classpath and the library to the previous and working version, that is:

```
classpath 'com.dynatrace.tools.android:gradle-plugin:8.247.1.1003'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.dynatrace.agent: agent-android: 8.247.1.1003'
```

and the problem no longer arises.
I hope this can help and save someone else's time, I took a lot of time to figure it out.